# Log all SOAP messages for Tomcat with Axis application

Tags: tomcat, soap, axis

To be able to debug them, I want to see what SOAP messages are sent/received from my Axis web service.

The hosting server is Tomcat.

How can logging of all the SOAP requests/responses be enabled  and where is the log file stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log the SOAP messages you will need to create a custom handler. [Axis handlers](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/handlers/package-summary.html) are called when handling the requests/responses so you just have to register your own. [Here is an example of how to log the messages](http://javaonline.free.fr/Frameworks/Axis/part-5.php).

If you want to write the messages to a file you could use [Log4j for example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/log4j-tutorial/log4j-tutorial.html). If you just want to debug the messages you can also use something like [Apache TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html).